# swift: change the color of the navigation bar

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I am using a `FirstViewController` with a red tint color navigation bar. When I go to next `SecondViewController` I use this code that clear navigation bar color:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
```

But when I go back to `FirstViewController` my navigation bar color is not red. It is clear. But it should be red. How to fix it?

code in `FirstViewController`:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
        self.navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .always
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
        
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor(red: 239/255, green: 210/255, blue: 166/255, alpha: 1.0)
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `barTintColor`, use **`backgroundColor`** to change the `navigationBar'r` color, i.e.

In **`FirstVC`**,

```
class FirstVC: UIViewController {
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
        self.navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .always
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = .red //here...
    }
}
```

In **`SecondVC`**,

```
class SecondVC: UIViewController {
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = .clear //here...
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: There is a problem ... In `FirstViewController` it is a TableViewController, I need that `navbar` in large mode will be clear but if I scroll down my tableView I need that navigation bar show red color. This doesn't work with `navigationBar.backgroundColor`

Comment: That needs adding code to manage the color based on scrolling. Adding barTintColor or backgroundColor solely won’t resolve the issue.

Comment: I don't know why, but if I use the code in my question, this is how it works. No additional code for scrolling behaviour. Can you give some tip on where to add the or scrolling behaviou code? Maybe there are already similar questions and answers?

Comment: You need to implement `scrollViewDidScroll(_:)` method in your `FirstVC`. In that identify the scroll direction and then change the `navigationBar's` color based on it.

Comment: Small clarification. Are you sure that your `navigation bar` in the` SecondVC` is really transparent and not white? Because in my application I am using an image as a background and if I write this `navigationBar.backgroundColor/tintColor/tintBackgroundColor .clear ` then I just get a black color in `navbar` area

Answer (score 0):

Set navigation bar's color of `FirstViewController` inside `ViewWillAppear` method.

Comment: Already. But it did not help. Add code from `FirstViewController ` in my question.

Comment: I have no idea about what I'm going to say, but I guess the problem is because of 'prefersLargeTitles' and 'largeTitleDisplayMode'. Temporary comments this two line of code and you see it will work fine!!

Answer (score 0):

Edit your question. It is not clear whether you want your navbar to be clear or red.
However, you can put this in `AppDelegate` :

```
let mainVC = MainViewController()
let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: mainVC)
navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = .clear// or .red
```

Comment: I have written clearly. In `FirstViewController ` red color.  In `SecondViewController ` clear color.

Comment: Ok, then change the title from `swift: change the color of the navigation bar to clear` to `swift: change the color of the navigation bar` :)

Comment: But your code doesn't help. If I use `navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = .clear` I see translucent dark background in navigation bar.

Comment: ok, try to add this line, too : `navigationController.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true`

Answer (score 0):

UINavigationBar.appearance().backgroundColor = .darkGray

Comment: this is not working